# Pre-populate redux-form causes double rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have created Simple form [following the guide in redux-form documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/examples/initializefromstate/) which prepopulate data from a reducer called `staticData`.

[SandBox Code can be seen here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mqy5yqyz2p)

The reducer is initialized with the state required for the prepopulation and there is no actioמ that calls it. (see the code below).

**Bottom Line**: Is it possible to pre-populate redux-form with only 1 render?

Comment: Ohai again. So what's different between your code and theirs? Theirs appears to render a single time.

Comment: The difference - they are populating with a button click. so it's not actually a "pre-populate". I am doing it programmatic without any need of user intervention.